Searching or removing a list from multi dimensional list in dart
Recently was working with dart multi-dimensional list, i have tried to remove a row(list) from a 2 dimensional list but the remove has no effect neither contains method has a match.
 List<List<int>> list = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
 print(list.contains([1,2])); // prints false also removing will not has an effect

while
 List<List<int>> list = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
 print(list.contains(list[0])); // prints true and successful remove

Why passing a list doesn't have a match, I know that comparison here is based on reference not the value, but shouldn't lists be canonicalized just like String and other numerical data types.

In Flutter lists are, by default only equal to themselves because the default equality behavior in Dart for objects (including lists) is based on identity, not on value. This means that two lists are considered equal only if they are the exact same instance in memory, not if they contain the same elements. Strings are the exceptions to the general rule for object comparison

@pskink yes, that's what canonicalization states(reference types that have the same value are pointing to the same memory location),shouldn't list be canonicalized? if not , the remove operation (in question) will be an overhead.

so you are asking why if you do: final a = [1, 2]; b = [1, 2]; both a and b dont  point to the same pointer in the memory or what?

@pskink , they don't but shouldn't they do, i think it's more efficient.

no, they should not, what if you change one element from them? for example a = [1,2]; b = [1,2]; now you want to do a[1] = 222 then b[1] would automagically change to 222

@pskink , missed that point, it's clear now. it seems a trade off

It seems correct,[1，2] != list[0].
you can see the implement of the contains function:
 bool contains(Object? element) {
    for (E e in this) {
      if (e == element) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

In your case,you can use listEquals such as :
list.retainWhere((item) => !listEquals(item, [1, 2]));


list[0] just accesses the first row in 2 dim list which is [1,2] , so [1,2] will equal [1,2] at least in value.

You can use listEqual() to compare list
var list = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4]
];
list.removeWhere(
  (element) {
    return listEquals(element, [1, 2]);
  },
);

Output
[log]  [[3, 4]]

